# Matrix Square Root with Negative Eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

Let **A** be a matrix

$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}41&12\\12&34\end{pmatrix}
$$

We know the **Eigenvalues** and **Eigenvectors** as

$$
Eigenvalues = \begin{pmatrix}50&25\end{pmatrix}\\Eigenvectors = \begin{pmatrix}0.8&-0.6\\0.6&0.8\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can simply then calculate the Squareroot of the matrix by

$$
Sqrt = \begin{pmatrix}0.8&-0.6\\0.6&0.8\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{50}&0\\0&\sqrt{25}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}0.8&-0.6\\0.6&0.8\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$

Which equates to
$$
Sqrt =
\begin{pmatrix}6.3255&0.9941\\0.9941&5.7456\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now what if i have a matrix like
$$
A = \begin{pmatrix}1&2\\3&4\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can see that the **Eigenvalues** and **Eigenvectors** are as follows
$$
Eigenvalues = \begin{pmatrix}-0.3722&5.3722\end{pmatrix}\\Eigenvectors = \begin{pmatrix}-0.8245&-0.4159\\0.5657&-0.9093\end{pmatrix}
$$

We can see that we now have a **negative** eigenvalue and the operation
$$
Sqrt = \begin{pmatrix}-0.8245&-0.4159\\0.5657&-0.9093\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\sqrt{-0.3722}&0\\0&\sqrt{5.3722}\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}-0.8245&-0.4159\\0.5657&-0.9093\end{pmatrix}^{-1}
$$
is no longer possible.

My question is, what technique i can use to handle this case. It would be fine if i only get the **magnitude** matrix of the complex square root matrix. I'm trying to program this and unfortunately the language that i'm coding this in doesn't support complex datatype. So i need an alternative way to get equalent results.

Comment: You can do complex numbers without a complex type by handling the real and imaginary parts separately rather like you would do it by hand.

Comment: The matrix $A$ is not positive semidefinite (it has negative eigenvalues), hence it does not have a real square root. If you are only interested in the magnitute of the complex square root, just take the square root of the absolute values of the eigenvalues, here $\sqrt{0.3722}$.

Comment: @johnny10 I'm interested in the Magnitude of the output of Matrix Squareroot. Applying absolute on the eigenvalues gives a totally different answer than expected. If eigenvalues are negative, the generated output(square root of the matrix) holds all the complex numbers. Note that the absolute of complex numbers is different than the absolute by converting eigenvalues to positive numbers.

Comment: @badjohn I can follow that technique but the issue is that I'm trying to solve this in matrix form and the language that I'm working with doesn’t allow complex matrices.

Comment: You can do a similar trick with separate real and imaginary matrices.

Comment: What do you mean by the magnitude of the matrix? I was assuming you meant the magnitude of the eigenvalues. If you mean the component-wise absolute value, I think the best will be, as pointed out before, to separate the diagonal square root matrix into imaginary and real part, compute the resulting imaginary and real part of the square root matrix and using these to get the magnitude of the entries of the square root.

Comment: Thanks, @badjohn. I have made it work by handling the complex and real parts separately. Works like a charm.